Filling 2 DIV with rising background colour from bottom to top
I would like to replicate this website part, only using CSS : https://www.branchfurniture.com/
What would be the best way? I'm talking about only the rising bar with filling colour that rise from bottom to top with also the labels texts outside the left bar & inside the right bar.
I want to incorporate this to a custom HTML section of my shopify.
Thanks!

Thanks!

This question is either too broad or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Have you investigated CSS animation? Though the problem with a pure CSS solution is it happens just the once and you can’t sense when the item enters or leaves the viewport.

Your browser can show you the source code of any web page you visit. You can study the code to learn how a particular effect has been achieved. It usually takes some time to find and assemble all the relevant code, but in this case the page is extremely well written and the code relevant to this chart is all together right there in the main page. Just a couple of minor adjustments and bingo! ... a working example:


function drawSavingsChart(){
  $("#bars li .bar").each( function( key, bar ) {
    var percentage = $(this).data('percentage');

    $(this).animate({
      'height' : percentage + '%'
    }, 1000);
  });
}

var element = document.getElementById('savings-chart');
var elementHeight = element.clientHeight;

document.addEventListener('scroll', animate);

// check if element is in view
function inView() {
  var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  var scrollY = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset; // number of pixels scrolled
  var scrollPosition = scrollY + windowHeight; // scroll position relative to window height
  var elementPosition = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + scrollY + elementHeight;

  if (scrollPosition > elementPosition) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

// animate element when it is in view
function animate() {
  // is element in view?
  if (inView()) {
    drawSavingsChart();
  }
}
section {
  height: 90vh;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#savings-chart {
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 25px auto 50px;
}

#savings-chart #y-labels {
  width: 30%;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-wrap: initial;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: initial;
  color: #989c99;
}

#savings-chart #y-labels li {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0;
  height: 25%;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#savings-chart #y-labels li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#savings-chart #bars {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

#savings-chart #bars li {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 125px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#savings-chart #bars li .bar {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  background: #AEB6B0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 1px;
  overflow: initial !important;
}

.bar-outline {
  width: 94px;
  margin: 3px;
  height: calc(100% - 6px);
  outline: 2px dashed #c3cec7;
}

#savings-chart #bars li .bar:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#savings-chart #bars li .bar.branch {
  background: #314438;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

#savings-chart #bars li .bar.branch:before {
  color: #989c99;
  content: 'Save up \A to ' attr(data-percentage) '%';
white-space: pre-wrap;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#savings-chart #bars li span.x-label {
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -4em;
  left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: #25352B;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 968px){
  #savings-chart #y-labels li {
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  .bar-outline {
    width: 74px;
  }

  #savings-chart #bars li {
    width:100px;
  }

  #savings-chart #bars li .bar {
    width:80px;
  }

  .savings-chart-logo {
    width: 73px;
  }

  #savings-chart #bars li span.x-label {
    width: 80px;
    font-size: 15px;
    bottom: -5em;
  }
  #savings-chart #bars li .bar.branch:before {
    font-size: 14px;
  }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px){
  #savings-chart #y-labels li {
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  #savings-chart #bars li {
    width: 80px;
  }

  #savings-chart #bars li .bar {
    width: 65px;
  }

  .bar-outline {
    width: 59px;
  }

  #savings-chart #bars li span.x-label {
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 65px;
  }

  .savings-chart-logo {
    width: 65px;
  }

  #savings-chart #bars li .bar.branch:before {
  font-size: 12px;
  }
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section style="background: orange;">Scroll down to see the chart</section>
<section style="background: purple;">Keep scrolling ...</section>

<div id="savings-chart">
  <ul id="y-labels">
    <li><span>Delivery, Assembly &amp; Disposal</span></li>
    <li><span>Dealer Markup</span></li>
    <li><span>Manufacturer Markup</span></li>
    <li><span>Materials &amp; Manufacturer</span></li>
  </ul>

  <ul id="bars">
    <li>
      <div data-percentage="100" class="bar"></div>
      <span class="x-label">Furniture Dealer</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div data-percentage="50" class="bar branch"></div>
      <div class="bar-outline"></div>
      <span class="x-label">
        <img class="savings-chart-logo" src="//www.branchfurniture.com/cdn/shop/t/552/assets/logo.png?v=37369424611378019991710516701" width="100" loading="lazy">
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<section style="background: green;">More content after the chart</section>



If your question is “how do I replicate this effect”, then the answer is to build on this code which already works. But if your question is “how do I replicate it without using Javascript” then that is a completely different thing. Firstly, why would you want to avoid Javascript? Secondly, the community will not simply write code for you. You need to ask a specific question about something you have attempted to do yourself.
